# Get the first textbox/checkbox/dropdown/file control on page and set focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the first form element (input element) that occurs on a page and set focus to it?
I would like to change the practice where I have to set focus manually in every single page to a certain element like this

```
$("#Clients").focus()
```

I want something universal, something that will figure out the first input automatically and put that code into a master page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selectors with [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(':input:first').focus();
});
```

Or since you said master page, you may have a certain content area or something, so just prefix that on the selector, for example:

```
$('#content :input:first').focus();
```

The `:input` selectors selects all input, textarea, select and button elements, so it'll grab the first of *any* kind of `<form>` input.

Comment: @mare - just trying to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more foolproof way of doing it by selecting only the visible and enabled inputs.

```
$(function() {
  $(':input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').first().focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives focus to the first textinput/textarea on the page

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=text], textarea').first().focus();
})
```